# Is it okay to ask an employee for interview tips on LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I've been selected for the second round of interview at a company (Data Engineer position).

I asked the HR about what the round would entail - she gave a generic answer that it would be a technical round with DS & Algo questions.
But the position I'm interviewing for will have other specific questions too. Glassdoor doesn't have many interview experiences about the DEngg position - one does mention data modeling & ETL.

I've sent connection requests to a few of their employees on LinkedIn (there are just a handful of people who've mention DEngg as their title or in their interests).

One of them has accepted, but I'm not sure whether I should ask them what type of questions are asked in the interviews?

Edit: I'm following this question (  [Is it appropriate to ask for internal interview tips?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/34747/85885) ).. Instead of asking for tips, should I ask about "what types of technical questions are covered? (SQL, data warehouse, specific database related)".

Comment: Are these people from the company you have applied to?

Comment: Yes, they are. Will edit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be inappropriate to communicate with employees and try to get hints on what the questions may be about.

It was already a bit inappropriate to form connections on LinkedIn with existing employees, though much more mildly.

At best, you'll be seen as unsure and desperate. At worst, dishonest and subvertive.

If the field is very broad, they will give you latitude.

This isn't an exam, this is real world. How you act and reason when you are unsure about something is a useful data point to them. These situations will occur throughout your career.